# quickfixj dynamically create setting can't alternatively connect between 2 hosts

Tags: quickfixj

I am creating the quickfixj initiator configuration dynamically in the code. Everything else works fine except that I have 2 host ips. With the old config file, it knows to round robin between my host and host1 ips. But with the new dynamically created settings, it always try the host, doesn't know how to go to the host1 ip.
I am doing as simple as follows:

```
settings.setString("SocketConnectHost", 100.100.100.11)
settings.setLong("SocketConnectPort", 5000)
settings.setString("SocketConnectHost1", 100.100.100.12)
settings.setLong("SocketConnectPort", 5000)
```

Anyone had experience with this before?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in your code in the last line? It has `SocketConnectPort` but should be `SocketConnectPort1`.

Comment: You are right, it's a typo. and it works right after I corrected it.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Once I corrected typo it works